# Formatting string with `{somestring}` in python causes python to confuse string with dictionary assignment

Tags: python

I am trying to format a string to pass to `os.popen()` so I can do some parsing in `awk`.  I'm using python 2.7.10.  When I try to format the string, python appears to think that I'm trying to assign a new key/value pair to a dictionary.

```
>>> path="xyz"
>>> string="awk {}".format(path)   #<--- This works as expected!
>>> string
'awk xyz'
>>> 
>>> string="awk 'BEGIN{FS=\"\t\"}{print $1}' {}"  #<--- This works, but not what I want
>>> string
'awk \'BEGIN{FS="\t"}{print $1}\' {}'
>>> 
>>> string="awk 'BEGIN{FS=\"\t\"}{print $1}' {}".format(path)  #<--- This fails b/c Python thinks I'm trying to do something with dictionaries?
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 'FS="\t"'
```

How do I format my `string` in the case where there are `{}` that are not intended to get formatted and ones that are?

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax

> If you need to include a brace character in the literal text, it can be escaped by doubling: `{{` and `}}`.